# How to output a directory file list prefixed with increasing numbers?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a bat file for our end users to run to generate a configuration file for a smart TV that is displaying images. This file requires lines to be output at as below:

```
0. /image1.png
1. /image2.png
2. /image3.png
```

I'm pretty new to this, so at the moment I've only really gotten to outputting this using the dir command which reads and outputs a list of all the pngs in the same directory:

```
dir /b *.png >> usb_schedulinglist.txt
```

outputs:

```
image1.png
image2.png
image3.png
```

Is there a way I can output the list above with the `<number>. /` in front, each line incrementing by 1, I assume it has to be done with a loop of some sort rather than the dir command.

Answer (score 1):

No loop needed, if you can live with one of the formats below:

```
dir /b *.png |findstr /n "^"
```

Output:

```
1:image1.png
2:image2.png
3:image3.png
```

or

```
dir /b *.png |find /n /v ""
```

Output:

```
[1]image1.png
[2]image2.png
[3]image3.png
```

To get the exact format `0. /image1.png`, a loop is needed (as shown by [Gerhard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60521428/2152082))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
(for %%a in (*.png) do (
   echo !num!. /%%~a
   set /a num+=1
  )
)>usb_scheduling.txt
```

We just run a loop through all `*.png` files, set a numeric value and increment it. Then print each result, with a leading number.

If however you still wanted to use `dir` for some reason, this does the same, but initiates more commands, so might be slightly slower.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
(for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.png') do (
    echo !num!. /%%~a
    set /a num+=1
  )
)>usb_scheduling.txt
```

I added the `/` as per the first example, so the above scripts will both output:

```
0. /image1.png
1. /image2.png
2. /image3.png
```